# Stitch function in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

Following PIG code is not working:

```
grunt> Register /usr/lib/pig/lib/piggybank.jar ;                  
grunt> define Stitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch();
grunt> data = load 'a' using PigStorage('|') ;                    
grunt> B = Stitch(data,data);
```

**Error:-**

```
2015-01-06 12:03:57,730 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - 
ERROR 1200: <line 12> Cannot expand macro 'Stitch'. 
Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.
Details at logfile: /home/hduser/nikhil/pig_1420524859398.log
```

Can someone explain whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues in your code
1. You can't  directly assign the output of `stitch` command to any relation. It should be projected as part of `FOREACH`  stmt.
2. `Stitch` command will take `only bags` as an input parameter, but you are passing the entire relation.

Can you fix the above two issue and retry your script.

**Sample example:**

**input:**

```
{(a,b),(e,f)}   {(c,d),(g,h)}
```

**PigScript:**

```
grunt> REGISTER /tmp/piggybank.jar;
grunt> DEFINE MyStitch org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch;
grunt> A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (B1:{T:(t1:chararray,t2:chararray)},B2:{T1:(t3:chararray,t4:chararray)});
grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE MyStitch(B1,B2);
grunt> DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
({(a,b,c,d),(e,f,g,h)})
```

**Reference:**
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/Stitch.html